# Atom Editor Golang - Go To Declaration not working

Tags: go, atom-editor

I've done a fresh install of atom and installed go-plus package. The one feature I can't get working is the "Go To Declaration" which is why I'm still stuck in sublime land... Does anyone know if this works with golang? I't appears that I need to have ctags for my project? Whats the best way to get this going for atom? I've tried installing other packages that geverate the ctags but I don't think that helped. Has anyone got this working? What did you do?

Comment: I struggled for weeks with Atom and Go To Declaration.  I gave up and took 1 minute to install Sublime Text which worked right out of the box, no packages, tags file, or any other configuration needed.

Comment: Did you install `godef` separately?

Answer (score 11):

Fresh install of `Atom 1.3.3` with `go-plus 3.5.2` and it worked.

By default, the shortcut is `Alt+Cmd+G`, but you can change it.

**Update December, 22th:**

With the latest update of `Atom (1.12.7)` and `go-plus (5.0.6)`, the `hyperclick` package (v 0.0.39) is installed and CMD+click will take you to the definition

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, Press ctrl-alt-g on the variable for which you want to do "go to declaration", Atom will ask if you want to install go-def, click yes, once installed it will show you a notification, after which Go to declaration works.

Answer (score 2):

It was two things that got `godef` working for me:

1. fixing GOROOT when go is installed by brew. You need to use the `libexec` subdirectory. See below.
2. understanding GOPATH. It's the *workspace*. In Intellij terminology, the GOPATH is the path to the project. It has as *immediate* subfolders `src`, `bin`, and other go-specific folders.

Below is what my `bash_profile` looks like.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/Documents/gocode
export GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.1/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

After making this change, atom (as well as emacs) started to work

Answer (score 1):

That might be related to the `godef` package, which has recently changed location.

See "[PR 239](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/pull/239)" (merged in [7a32e22](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/commit/7a32e22c2c9bca392c4bd41ffef3dfc2cafc791e)):

> The godef package has been [moved to github](https://github.com/rogpeppe/godef) (see http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/cmd/godef).
>   This change will allow Get Missing Tools to install it.

That will be available in go-plus 3.4.2 (currently I see 3.4.1 in my Atom package list)

Comment: I'm using 3.4.2 go-plus and it's still not working. I'm really very stumped with this one. My GOPATH is set ok no errors from the editor it can find go-def everything looks ok.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @mcbain83 try install it from the command line: `go install github.com/rogpeppe/godef`: you should see a `godef.exe` in `%GOPATH%\bin` (I am seeing one myself in my environment). Once in place, the Go-Plus / Display Go Information does list godef correctly.

Comment: Nope still not working. When the package loads in atom there are no errors. The gopath is set to my workspace and the $GOAPTH/bin dir has all the right exe's in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had goplus and it wasn't working but the [godef atom package](https://atom.io/packages/godef) worked like a charm

`apm install godef`