# Add Cmd+Click navigation to definition in Atom editor with Golang?

Tags: go, atom-editor

Does anyone know if it's possible to jump around code in a project by Control/Cmd+Click? I keep right-clicking and doing "Go to Definition" but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's not a programming problem.

Comment: Masood, Its about a software tool commonly used by programmers. So should be [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ben, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455131/atom-editor-golang-go-to-declaration-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Go to Definition" option is built-in to Atom and requires ctags, which is a bit of work to set up for Go.  Instead, you can install the [`navigator-go`](https://atom.io/packages/navigator-go) package, which will allow you to jump to definition with a keyboard shortcut.

If you prefer cmd+click as opposed to a keyboard shortcut, you can also install:

- [`go-hyperclick`](https://atom.io/packages/go-hyperclick) **
- [`hyperclick`](https://atom.io/packages/hyperclick)

** Note:* `navigator-go` was recently renamed, and `go-hyperclick` still points at the old repo, so you may get some warnings about a missing package until [this PR](https://github.com/zheng1/go-hyperclick/pull/3) is merged.